# How to call local variable into another page of php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to call a local variable into another PHP page.
On page referal_income.php i used a local variable $income, and I want to fetch the store information into another page main_balance.php

I want to do this because $income contain income of member and main_balance page is used to display of all incomes.

Code of referal_income.php

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT userid,amount FROM personal WHERE sponserid='$_SESSION[userid]'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error($conn)))

{
$total[]=$row['amount'];

$income=array_sum($total);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['userid']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['amount']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['amount'] * 0.05."</td>";
echo "<td>". $income * 0.05."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Rizier123 Question is very simple....I want to fetch the stored information of $income into another php page...

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rizier123 i m fully confused that how to code for this.

Comment: @roullie Can you please code...

Comment: @AnkitBhatanagar You could include the file or use `$_SESSION`

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php, then try implementing it yourself...

Answer (score 2):

you can use session for passing variable value to other pages like this

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

$query = "SELECT userid,amount FROM personal WHERE sponserid='$_SESSION[userid]'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error($conn)))
{
$total[]=$row['amount'];

$income=array_sum($total);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['userid']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['amount']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['amount'] * 0.05."</td>";
echo "<td>". $income * 0.05."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

$_SESSION['income'] = $income;

?>
```

on other page

```
<?php     
session_start();     
$income = $_SESSION['income'];
?>
```

Comment: There is no need to update session variable in each iteration.

Comment: this is ok. if there is only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use $_SESSION for store $income or in 'main_balance.php' you include 'referal_income.php' and call $income.